# How can I find current SSH protocol version of the current connection?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos6

I connect to a Linux machine (CentOS 6.4) using [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY). Except from fact that I can set PuTTY to only use one type of protocol, how can I find the current SSH connection's version (SSH1 or SSH2)?

Comment: It can help to show what research you've already done

Comment: @DrewKhoury I only tried with google to find an answer to this but no result found regardin this. No one explains how can I see the current connection (in use) protocol (ssh1 or ssh2).

Answer (score 65):

Once you are in you say:

```
ssh -v localhost
```

it will tell you the exact version of the server.

Comment: It doesn't seem that this shows the current connection type.

Answer (score 40):

An alternative way.

As [cstamas](https://serverfault.com/users/6491/cstamas) suggested, you can use `ssh -v localhost`. Uou simply ssh to yourself 127.0.0.1 on verbose mode, which will display debugging messages of the progress. Yes, through this process you can look at the top of the communication and you can get the SSH version that you are currently running.

But *if* you read the `ssh man` page, you will find the `-V` option on `ssh` more useful. Taken out the [`ssh` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh):

> -V    Display the version number and exit.
>
> -v    Verbose mode. Causes ssh to print debugging messages about its progress. This is helpful in debugging connection, authentication, and configuration problems. Multiple -v options increase the verbosity. The maximum is 3.

So I think it would be better to simply do `ssh -V` and get something similar to:

```
> ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

Comment: That's the version of the _program_, not the protocol used for a connection. As a 3-year earlier answer correctly explained, the very same program can support both SSH1 and SSH2 protcols, or not, depending on configuration.

Answer (score 15):

#### PuTTY

In *Session*, *Logging*, select the *"SSH packets and raw data"* radio button. Select the log file as *putty.log* in a location of your choice. Make the connection. You should see:

```
Event Log: Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
Event Log: Using SSH protocol version 2
```

See below for details on what SSH-2.0 means.

#### Other Methods

You could also try using the telnet client, but point to port 22:

```
telnet test1 22
```

When you connect you will see:

> Trying 192.168.144.145... 
> Connected to test1. 
> Escape character is '^]'. 
> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3

The last line is the one to look for:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
```

If it says `SSH-2.0` then that is good, the SSH server you connected to supports only SSH protocol version 2. It will not support connections from SSH V1 protocol clients.

If however you see:

SSH-1.99-OpenSSH_5.3

Then that means that the server end is still supporting SSH protocol version 1. It has something like this in it's `sshd_config` file:

```
Protocol 1,2
```

Protocol 1 is vulnerable and should not be used.

So to get that straight. If you see SSH-2 when you telnet to port 22 of the remote server then you can only be using SSH protocol version 2 as the server does not support protocol 1.

As per cstamas answer above, the `-v` flag will show a line:

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
```

or:

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
```

You want to see `version 2.0` there.

Comment: Re *"...is still supporting SSL protocol..."*: Do you mean *"...is still supporting SSH protocol..."*?

Answer (score 5):

I like this better:

```
$ echo ~ | nc localhost 22
SSH-1.99-OpenSSH_3.9p1
Protocol mismatch.
$
```

The benefit here is that it can be done programatically since the connection isn't held open. For Python, try:

```
ssh_protocol = float(re.search(r"SSH-(\d.\d+)").group(1))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get this pretty quickly using netcat from your local machine, for example:

```
$ nc [IP_ADDRESS] 22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
```

Comment: Yep. `"SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u6"` for an old Raspberry Pi (internal). I also got the exact same result as you for some web hosting ([Red Hat Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) based?).

Answer (score 1):

To get more details you can use this:

```
    rpm -qi openssh
```

```
Name        : openssh
Version     : 7.4p1
Release     : 21.el7
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Пт 17 янв 2020 12:21:57
Group       : Applications/Internet
Size        : 1991172
License     : BSD
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Пт 23 авг 2019 00:37:23, Key ID 24c6a8a7f4a80eb5
Source RPM  : openssh-7.4p1-21.el7.src.rpm
Build Date  : Пт 09 авг 2019 04:40:49
Build Host  : x86-01.bsys.centos.org
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
Vendor      : CentOS
URL         : http://www.openssh.com/portable.html
Summary     : An open source implementation of SSH protocol versions 1 and 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The only method I am aware of requires that one has sufficient privileges to view the `ssh` log entries in `/var/log/auth.log`.

```
$ echo $SSH_CONNECTION 
127.0.0.1 12375 127.0.0.1 22
```

The first and second fields of the `SSH_CONNECTION` variable indicate the source IP address and source port of my connection. By `grep`-ing for those values in `/var/log/auth.log`, I can find the log entry from when my SSH connection was authenticated.

```
$ sudo grep -F ' from 127.0.0.1 port 12375 ' /var/log/auth.log | grep ssh
Jun 26 16:29:52 morton sshd[20895]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for jim from 127.0.0.1 port 12375 ssh2
```

This log entry tells me that my current connection is using the SSH 2 protocol. Of course, if the `ssh` session has been open for several days, the log entry may be in `/var/log/auth.log.0` or some older `auth.log` file.

Answer (score 0):

One can try to login using **SSH -1** , and shall be rejected if this version is disabled:

```
$ ssh -1 user@server_name
SSH protocol v.1 is no longer supported
```

SSH 2 shall be accepted:

```
$ ssh -2 user@server_name
```